# How to successfully access the database on another computer using java and jdbc and sql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have this database on another pc and i want to access it by using a connection string like this.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1/dbtina","root","1234");
```

the "dbtina" is our database. the "1234" is our password. and we have configured our ip to be like that because we are using a wired connection (peer to peer).

```
Exception: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.*
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **3306** port on the firewall of the computer where the DB is.

Comment: Well, first of all, you could provide some details...What OS are you using on the computer with the DB? What kind of firewall or antivirus software are you using there? Judging by your comment, I'd also like to ask what's the IP of the computer where the program is run...

Answer (score 3):

Simply disable firewall. or open the port 3306 for mysql
use this link if it helps

[manually open port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308127)

even after doing this you might get security exception. use mysql `GRANT` query to give permissions.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_base.* TO db_user @'ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';

[grant example](http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/grant.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the firewall on the database computer to allow the traffic from different computer on specific Port.

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code accordingly:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/dbtina",
  "root","1234");
```